# Cheapest way to remotely control 120v outlet via ethernet?

Tags: remote, ethernet, electrical-power

What is the cheapest solution to be able to remotely power cycle a regular 120V outlet via ethernet?  I've seen solutions like iBoot, but they're really expensive.  Is there a cheap way to remotely power cycle equipment?

Comment: +1, I also need an answer for this.

Comment: Define a threshold for "Cheap".

Comment: Under $100, preferably under $50.

Comment: In what currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambery's "[Remote Power Switch](http://www.ambery.com/pr2reposwweb.html)" is less expensive than the iBoot. It's still over $100 though.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a [X10 module](http://www.x10.com/automation/sr227_s.html) strapped to a ShivaPlug or other small embedded system.

Answer (score 2):

I bought "IP Power 9258T" for $75, but I have not tested it yet. Physically the device is somewhat larger than other similar devices that I have seen, but seems well built.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities:

- [Web Power Switch](http://www.digital-loggers.com/lpc.html)
- [Unity Ethernet Power Controller](http://www.unityelectronics.com/products/4057/Unity_Ethernet_Power_Controller_II_Power_Switch_16_Plus_2_Outlets_Auto_Ping_EPCR2_Retail)
- [Remote Power Switch](http://www.ambery.com/reposw.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a review of a device that looks promising: http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/163-Ethernet-Power-Switch.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/ip-power-control

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/remote-reboot

There is "Remote network IP LAN power plug switch -web/hangout control w auto-reboot/timer" currently priced at $65 and refurbished iBoot at $50.